# Transparent texture with OpenGL ES without using the alpha channel

Tags: opengl-es, transparency, texturing

Is it possible with OpenGL ES to texture a quad in such a way that all pixel (0,0,0) of the texture are not drawn while all the others are drawn? I have RGB888 images and the black color (0,0,0) is to be considered as completely transparent, while the other colors are completely opaque.

Thx

Answer (score 0):

You could apply a fragment shader which sets the alpha color for pixels with RGB=(0,0,0) to 0. See [here](http://www.opengl.org/documentation/glsl/) for details on writing a fragment shader.

Comment: Thx, but what if i have OpenGL ES 1.1 or below?

Comment: Would the Stencil Buffer do what you want? See section 4.1.5 of the [OpenGL ES Spec](http://www.khronos.org/registry/gles/specs/1.1/es_full_spec_1.1.12.pdf).